# Minecraft Resourse packs issue

Tags: nautilus, java, minecraft

I open minecraft resource packs folder button, it opens it in firefox
I installed 16.04.1 LTS but I try this to <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>f2</kbd> then this to

```
nautilus ~/.minecraft/resourcepacks
```

for it but... it just says

```
"Unable to find the requested file. Please check the spelling and try again.
unhandled error message: Error when getting information for file '/home/system32/.minecraft/resourcepacks': No such file or directory"
```

Comment: `Unable to find the requested file. Please check the spelling and try again.` Maybe resourcepacks isn't there like that error message said. 
Can you see resourcepacks in the terminal if you run `cd ~/.minecraft/ && ls` ?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using the right path. I've never seen a **system32** folder in an Ubuntu installation.

To locate the file you are looking for open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> and issue the command `find . -name "resourcepacks"`If the file exists you will get output of the full path and name similar to `/path/to/resourcepacks`

Comment: Most likely the path is located at `/home/(username)/.minecraft/resourcepacks`, because that is the default.

Comment: @DavidCole-GrammarPolice Likely yes. Give a man a fish he'll eat for a day. Teach him to fish he'll eat for a lifetime! ;-)

Comment: Love that quote!

Comment: I hope you get it back!

Comment: ok i fixed it becuase minecraft not make folder ok u can go

Answer (score 0):

`Unable to find the requested file. Please check the spelling and try again.` Maybe resourcepacks isn't there like that error message said. If the resourcepacks file is there, you should be able to see it in the terminal if you run the following command:

```
cd ~/.minecraft/ && ls
```

If the results of `cd ~/.minecraft/ && ls` show that the `~/.minecraft/` folder does not exist, you can create it and move the resourcepacks file into it.